# Binding generic parameter to a custom model binder in Web API

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

In WebAPI's Register() method, I'm binding a specific parameter type to a custom model binder like so:

```
config.BindParameter(typeof(Expression<Func<Person, bool>>), new CustomModelBinder());
```

How does one go about replicating the same for generic types? In addition to Person, I have a lot more models and DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it by using a marker interface that all your DTOs implement.

```
public interface IDataTransferObject {}

public class Person : IDataTransferObject
{
    ...
}
```

Then you should be able to bind these to your custom Model Binder.

```
config.BindParameter(typeof(Expression<Func<IDataTransferObject, bool>>), new CustomModelBinder());
```